# Check if mouse is over marker Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API with Javascript

I currently have the following code in my `initMap` function:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function (event) {
  currentPos = event.latLng;
  console.log(currentPos.lat() + " ... " + currentPos.lng());
});
```

When I right-click on areas of the map, certain methods are called in that specific area.

But when I hover over the marker (which is a circle), the `currentPos` remains the same as it was just before the mouse went over the circle.

i.e - the `currentPos` is somewhere on the border of the circle, yet my mouse is hovering inside the circle.

Is there anyway to either

- Activate the `mousemove` listener, even when hovering over a marker, or
- Recognise that the mouse is over a marker

This might make things easier for me.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: set the `clickable`-option of the marker to false

Comment: I just realised, I would like to be able to drag the marker... And to do this I need to set `clickable` to `true`. Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: For me a marker is draggable(assuming you've set the `draggable`-option to true) even  when `clickable` is set to false

Comment: This is not the case, I've tried several web browsers. Is is possible that a newer version of the API is causing this? It's quite irritating. Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/wprm8u00/  ....tested in relase/experimental/frozen-version(with FF,Chrome,IE,Opera)

Comment: Wow! That's odd, I wonder what's up with mine. I'll try fix it.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using a `Circle` instead of a `Marker`, which I didn't expect would interfere. Does this mean there's no solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger the `mousemove`-event for the `map` in the `mousemove` of the `circle`:

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      zoom: 14,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5498783, 13.425209099999961)
    }),
    ctrl = document.createElement('code');
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(ctrl);
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    center: map.getCenter(),
    radius: 100,
    draggable: true
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(e) {
    ctrl.innerHTML = e.latLng.toUrlValue();
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'mousemove', function(e) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(this.getMap(), 'mousemove', {
      latLng: e.latLng
    })

  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
code {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
```

Comment: You sir, are a legend!